# Can't add hair to particle system

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, hair

At the moment I am trying to make a mustache because I thought a hairy ball was to simple. I created a model in a "mustache shape" and added the hair. Now I have the problem that I can't add any hair by using the "Add" brush. I tied to change different values a bit but nothing seams to make it work.

Because I probably explained it poorly here is a video of the problem: https://youtu.be/1DHYQZPMXbc

[image]

I hope I made the problem I am having clear and that someone can help me with it.

Comment: I checked your file and found nothing...You can add another particle system and work on it or start again. Your particle system seems broken. Can't help you more

Answer (score 2):

Click on "Free Edit" and change the "Emit From:" setting in the Emission panel from Volume to Faces.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why will *Faces* method of emitting particles allow adding new particles with Add brush as opposed to *Volume* method? Note also that pressing Free Edit button will erase all the particles changes done in Particle Edit mode

Comment: The volume selection "emits hair particles from the volume of an enclosed mesh." OPs mesh isn't enclosed so there's no actual volume to emit from. I'm surprised that it emitted any hair at all. There were good mesh faces and that fixed the problem. The Free edit option was necessary and, given that no more hair was going to be added under the settings as they were, keeping the particle changes was pointless.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see your baking settings in the video, but this behavior can be caused if your particles aren't baked, or if they are baked to a Disk Cache.

From [the Manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/particles/mode.html):

> Only Frames Baked to Memory are Editable!
>
> If you cannot edit the particles, check that you are not baking to a Disk Cache.

To change this, uncheck "Disk Cache" in your cache settings.

[image]

Comment: I am working with a particle system without physics so I'm unable to use/see the cache settings. The main problem I have is that I can't use the add brush in the particle edit mode. When I try to add hair with this brush nothing happens/ it doesn't add hair.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my case, the solution was to select *Particle* in the *Editing Type* dropdown of the *Tool Options*.